# How can I get the roles for the currently logged-in user?

Tags: users, 8

How can I get the roles for the currently logged-in user, in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7, it could be achieved by accessing `$GLOBALS['user']->roles;`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Something like:

```
$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$roles = $current_user->getRoles();
```

will return an array like:

```
Array
(
  [0] => authenticated
  [1] => administrator
  [2] => some_other_role
)
```

where the array values are role IDs (equivalent to the machine name of the role in Drupal 7).  In OO code, use the appropriate mechanism get the current user from the container, eg

```
$current_user = $container->get('current_user');
```

Comment: To check if a user is at least one of multiple given roles: `if (!empty(array_intersect(['administrator', 'some_other_role'], \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles()))) { ...`.

Comment: That approach worked for me perfectly. Thanks @leymannx !